# Battery Drain with Kubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, laptop, battery, performance

I recently fresh installed Kubuntu 22.04.1 coming from 20.04. The upgrade is great but I have an Issue with battery and performance. On 20.4 there were no power profiles. The laptop always ran quietly, fast and never heat up. Battery was great. On kubuntu 22.04.1 the power profile is set to Balanced, but the battery drains pretty fast and for the first time in years the system is starting to use the fan due to heat. I switched the power profile to Power Save and it runs much cooler and better battery life, but also performance is worse than using 20.4. Driver seems to be intel_pstate. Any ideas?

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.25.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.95.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-46-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz
Memory: 7.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620
Manufacturer: HP
Product Name: HP EliteBook x360 1030 G4

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the app Latte Dock. When upgrading Kubuntu 22.04.1 I also enabled backports and upgraded Plasma to 25 using the method explained by the Kubuntu website https://kubuntu.org/news/plasma-5-25-for-jammy-22-04-available-via-ppa/

Apparently Latte Dock is not compatible with the latest plasma so it would freeze and cause high memory spikes. I was able to fix it by installing the Git version of Latte Dock following these instructions https://github.com/KDE/latte-dock/blob/master/INSTALLATION.md

The laptop is running way smoother and won't heat up after updating latte dock. Battery seems to have improved by over 40% as well.